# update global variable from a function inside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to organize my project a bit, by creating different modules with different functions. But to be effective I need these functions to update my variables in my "app.js" file.

The code underneath should update and log the variable "name" as soon as I run the "myFunction" located in the "custom_module.js" file. 
But what I get is:

> Hello undefined

app.js

```
var name;
var module = require('./custom_module.js');
module.myFunction();
console.log("Hello " + name);
```

custom_module.js

```
var myFunction = function(){
    name = "Test"
}

module.exports.myFunction = myFunction;
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Better rethink your architecture before its too late. Shared mutable state is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach it to the global object... That's `global` in Node and `window` in the browser.

```
// app.js
window.name = 'Foo';

// custom_module.js
var myFunction = function(){
    window.name = "Bar";
}
```

P.S. Don't do this. Shared global variables are (usually) always evil.

Comment: When you say I shouldn't go with global variables what would be an alternative to them, because I don't want to have a file that has hundreds and hundreds lines of code... Is there maybe a guide, you can suggest me which teaches me how I can split up my app into multiple files?

Comment: You are already doing it with modules. Your small, modular components can have properties - save your state in those.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the scope of `name` as you've defined it is only inside the function. You need to move the scope outside. Something like

app.js

```
var module = require('./custom_module.js');
var name = module.myFunction();
console.log("Hello " + name);
```

custom_module.js

```
var myFunction = function(){
    return "Test";
}

module.exports.myFunction = myFunction;
```